# Error when combining biblatex, hyperref and latexdiff

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, latexdiff

I've stumbled upon a weird incompatibility between the [hyperref](/questions/tagged/hyperref) and [biblatex](/questions/tagged/biblatex) packages and [latexdiff](/questions/tagged/latexdiff). If there is an added citation with more authors than the [biblatex](/questions/tagged/biblatex) `maxcitenames` parameter, then I get two pairs of errors when compiling:

> Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. }
>
> Missing } inserted. }

#### MCVE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
%DIF LATEXDIFF DIFFERENCE FILE

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[
            backend=bibtex,
            style=authoryear-ibid,
            defernumbers=true,
            maxnames=1,  %%% OPTION ONE: Change this to a number greater or equal to the maximal number of authors
            ]
{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{dr1957cat,
    title={The Cat in the Hat},
    author={Seuss, Dr. and Ginsburg, Avi},
    series={Beginner books},
    year={1957},
    publisher={Random House}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%DIF PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF and edited by me for the MCVE

\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{color}\definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}\definecolor{BLUE}{rgb}{0,0,1} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddtex}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}\uwave{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE

\providecommand{\DIFaddbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE

% OPTION THREE: Define this as:{\DIFadd}[1]{#1} and lose the intent
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\DIFaddtex{#1}}{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF END PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF

\begin{document}

\DIFaddbegin
  \DIFadd{  %%% OPTION TWO: Comment out this line and the corresponding }
    \textcite{dr1957cat}
  }         %%% OPTION TWO: This is the corresponding }
\DIFaddend
. 'twas a good book.

\end{document}
```

I've figured out a few workarounds (noted in the MCVE), but can't figure out if this is a bug, by design, or why it happens. So, why do I have to use the workarounds?

P.S. The error occurs after this sequence (i.e. not before compiling the bibtex)

> pdflatex mcve.tex
> bibtex mcve
> pdflatex mcve.tex

The problem can also be reproduced in

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{{\penalty-1}\space}

\begin{document}
  \uwave{\cite{sigfridsson}}

  \uwave{{\penalty-1}\space}
\end{document}
```

where the first line in the document environment causes the error, the second one is fine.

Comment: Interesting problem. A bit of experimenting shows that it is specifically the `\bibstring{andothers}` (which gives "et al.") command that causes trouble. Not sure why though ... (Also `\bibstring{ibidem}` for example is fine)

Comment: A bit more digging shows that the problem is probably with `\addabbrvspace` (which is used in the `andothers` bibstring) and that someone here doesn't like explicit penalties set via `\penalty`.

Comment: @moewe I must say that I have no idea what you're talking about. But I guess I asked for that when I asked the question. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, my knowledge about what is going on here is pretty much exhausted with the two comments above. Would you mind if I edited your question with a slightly more stripped down version of your code example?

Comment: @moewe Feel free.

Comment: The second example is pretty clear MWE and needs attention.